# How to download pdf file from a content CDN using next js 13

Tags: javascript, pdf, next.js, download, cdn

I need to download a file using next js 13. I get an object from API which contains field 'path_to_file' with path to file at content CDN.

Example link to file: https://[environment_name.]my-CDN/<path_to_file>.

I want to download a file by clicking link with href="path_to_file"

How to properly join my CDN with href?